# Subquery help Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have 2 tables in my schema:

1 - covid_data (relevant columns: country, year, week, cases). Data example:

```
+-------+------+-----+-------+
|country| year | week| cases |
+-------+------+-----+-------+
|USA    | 2022 |  1  | 58488 |
|USA    | 2022 |  2  | 65154 |
|USA    | 2022 |  3  | 74154 |
|USA    | 2022 |  4  | 84158 |
|USA    | 2022 |  5  | 96997 |
+-------+------+-----+-------+
```

countries_of_the_world (relevant column: country)

```
+-------+
|country|
+--------
|USA    | 
|France | 
|Brazil | 
|Germany| 
|China  | 
+-------+
```

I need to retrieve the most recent record for each country in **countries_of_the_world**. The rule for the "most recent record" is determined by higher value in **year** and higher value in **week**. For example, right now we are at week 6, year 2022.

I did the following code:

```
SELECT country, max(year), max(week) 
FROM covid_data
WHERE week in (
    SELECT MAX(week)
    FROM covid_data
    WHERE year in (
        SELECT MAX(year)
        FROM covid_data
        GROUP BY year) 
    GROUP BY week)
GROUP BY country;
```

but is retrieving like the infos apart. For example **week 53** for **year 2022**, because this week is "available" for the past year:

```
+--------------------+
|country| year | week|
+--------------------+
|USA    | 2022 | 53  |
+--------------------+
```

How can I do this query including joining with every country with the other table?

Comment: Thanks Stu, but I guess not. I believe my problem goes a little bit deeper

Comment: Questions on SQL benefit greatly from a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Stu Updated. Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but does the following give what you are after?

```
with c as (
  select country, cases, 
    Row_Number() over(partition by country order by year desc, week desc) rn
  from covid_data
)
select country, cases
from c
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: work like a charm, thanks. Can you explain further the usage of "Row_Number() over(partition...", please

Comment: It's easier to follow if you run just the query in the CTE; partition essentially groups rows by the country and then applies a sequential number to each row, ordered as specified, within each group, so by ordering year and week descending, the most recent week/year for each country starts with number 1, which you then filter on.